# How to do hexadecimal subtraction and how does it affect the arm flags

Tags: assembly, arm

I am new to ARM.

So I have this following instruction

```
SUBS R2, R4, R3
Initial condition N = 0, Z = 0, C = 1, V = 0, Q = 0
```

values in register are signed

```
R2 = 0000 0000 H
R3 = 7FFF FFFE H 
R4 = 8000 0002 H
```

One way I learned was to directly subtract

```
  8000 0002 H
- 7FFF FFFE H 
-------------
  0000 0004 H
```

but using two complement `-7FFF FFFE H --> +8000 0002`

```
  8000 0002 H
+ 8000 0000 H 
-------------
1 0000 0004 H
```

But this doesn't make any sense since `8000 0002 H` is a negative number subtracted by `7FFF FFFE H` is a positive number which should give me a big negative number. Is it an overflow, is the carry from the initial condition affected?

Because in the solution book, I'm getting C=0 and no overflow.

Comment: the beauty of twos complement is that for add/subtract there is no "negative" number nor "positive" number the signness of the number is in the eye of the programmer not the logic.  you can use the same logic for both signed and unsigned interpretations of the bits.

Comment: you forgot a borrow in your subtraction both have the exact same result (as they should).  both have the carry out set.   the result for a 32 bit operation is 0000 0004 anyway.  we cant magically add bits to registers implemented in logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subtraction you have to borrow, you forgot to borrow off the top bit

For example in base 10.

```
 500
-600
====
```

we cross out the 5 and borrow from the zero next to it (infinitely)

```
1400
```

- 600
  =========

If you want to subtract in base 2 you also have to actually borrow.

```
 000
-100
=====

1000
-100
=====
```

correcting your subtraction:

```
 1
  8000 0002 H
- 7FFF FFFE H 
-------------
  0000 0004 H
```

Using twos complement (as a processor would see it)

```
          1
  8000 0002
+ 8000 0001
==============


 1000000001
  8000 0002
+ 8000 0001
==============
  0000 0004
```

Twos complement does not break math, that is the point it works nicely with base two logic implementation converting a subtract into an add which is simpler logic (well some may debate it being simpler, I think you need a carry in/out and a separate borrow in/out for subtract but for add just the carry)

The register is limited to 32 bits you cannot magically add bits to the register to make it 33 bits.

You can do experiments to see if you think arm is one that inverts the carry in and carry out for a subtract.  Some architectures do, some do not.

Never assume that carry FLAG = carry OUT (for compare/subtract), always confirm.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, about the overflow flag, since the value cannot be represented within the 32 bits ,and since  a positive number is subtracted from a negative number and the result is positive, the V=1 right?

Comment: signed overflow (V) is different from the unsigned overflow (C).  but signed overflow happens when on the msbit the carry in is not equal to the carry out.  in this case that upper bit for your example 0x8... 0x8... is carry in of 0 and carry out of 1 so yes signed overflow.    if you do a table then another way to see it is if the msbits (operands) are the same and the result is not the same then it is a signed overflow.  so again in this case the data bits are both one and the result is 0 so signed overflow.

Comment: Note the arm cores are not broken BTW, they compute flags properly...